# Token Authentication in Meteor

Tags: ios, node.js, api, authentication, meteor

I would like to expose an API from my meteor application for my iOS application. My plan is to create a RESTful API and have the iOS application authenticate using a token. I want to store an hash of the token in the User model provided by the `Accounts` package and have the user send the token with each request to authenticate with the hash.

How can I do this?

I have seen found the `Random.secret([n])` in meteor [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random), so I will be able to create a token with this method, but **couldn't find a way to encrypt it**. I see that some meteor packages (account-password?) uses `npm-bcrypt` package but couldn't find any information on how to use it.

Comment: bcrypt is not encryption, it is a key derivation function for passwords similar to PBKDF2. See: [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I've used bcrypt to create a hash password on meteor server side. Smth like this will do it :

```
meteor add npm-bcrypt
```

Then, when receiving the password you can use

```
bcrypt.hash()
```

If you're looking for Auth Token generator with expiring time & stuff, you can have a look at jwt.

Comment: I am actually looking for a auth token generator but couldn't find one. I search for a jwt package for meteor and just one came up for google service.

Comment: check out this links I'm posting here, Meteor does not recommend cookies & token auth : https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/14/session-cookies ; Try this link for a meteor hack regarding auth : https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html